# Стилизация селекта с помощью css

Tags: html, css

http://fotki.yandex.ru/users/soledar06081984/view/959385?page=0
возможно ли создать такой селект как на картинке только с помощью css.
т.е. при выборе пункта текст заменяеться в большом поле на выбранный.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исключительно средствами CSS -- нет, насколько я знаю. Есть псевдокласс :indeterminate, для задания стиля в случае, если ни один вариант не выбран, но:

- Он ещё не введён в спецификацию:

> Note: Radio and checkbox elements can
> be toggled by the user, but are
> sometimes in an indeterminate state,
> neither checked nor unchecked. This
> can be due to an element attribute, or
> DOM manipulation.
>
> A future version of this specification
> may introduce an :indeterminate
> pseudo-class that applies to such
> elements.

И, как следствие, соответствующее свойство устанавливается только вручную, средствами JS.

- Неизвестно, будет ли он применим к спискам.
- На данный момент он не поддерживает свойство content, что было бы логично, а псевдоклассы :before и :after не работают с полями формы (я, по крайней мере, не смог этого добиться).

Используйте средства html для этого.

Comment: Спасибо! Я тоже не смог добиться этого результата только css. Только с помощью JS.